# how to run a dialog from the code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design

i'm coding a c# application using material design

here is my UserControl's xaml code :

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MediCare"
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes" x:Name="Usc1" "
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="900" Width="600">
<materialDesign:DialogHost x:Name="Dialog" >
    <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
        <Grid Width="300" Height="100">
            <TextBlock Text="DIALOG TEST"/>
            <Button Command="{x:StaticmaterialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}" Content="CloseDialog"/>
        </Grid>
    </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
    <Grid>
          <Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}" Content="CloseDialog" />
    </Grid>
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

i've a button with the command `Command="{x:Static 
 materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}"` to open my dialog, but my purpose is to open it through the .xaml.cs, how can i do ?

Comment: `DialogHost.Show()`?

Comment: i searched in the dialogHost properties and methods, there is no .show() or .open() . run() !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the dialog to show using `Dialog.IsOpen = true;`

Comment: i've already tried this, but it didn't show it because just after the Dialog.IsOpen = true; instruction i use to clean my window xD this is why i beleive it didn't work... thanks man :')